# RoR - counting unique values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner at RoR and I am toying around with a database that has 6000 rows of data. Since there is so much data to begin with, I have the index table displaying only rows of data that have unique item names by using this in the controller/index view.

```
@glyphs_test = Glyph.group(:item)
```

Alongside each row, I want to display the number of times that particular item appears in the entire database.
When I try this, it works but I don't know how to print it out onto the index.

```
Glyph.group(:item).uniq.count
```

results with, for example:

```
=> {"Eternal Fire" => 8, "Glyph of Adrenaline Rush" => 74} etc...
```

Even if I was able to print out the number only in this, how can I match it up with the table? I think I am missing something crucial here. I am able to do this in the individual record by using this in the show#controller but not in index#controller.

```
@glyph = Glyph.find(params[:id])
@glyphs = Glyph.where(["item = ?", @glyph.item]).order('net_gain ASC')
```

Thank you in advance for any advice. Perhaps I should do something more simpler but there must be a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through your results hash with something like the following

```
@glyph_counts = Glyph.group(:item).uniq.count

@glyph_counts.each do |key, value|
   #key is the item, value is the count, using key and value as the object is a hash
   # do your printing here
end
```

Or if you are iterating through your glyphs and trying to get the count from the results, you could do the following

```
@glyphs = Glyph.all
@glyph_counts = Glyph.group(:item).uniq.count

@glyph.each do |glyph|
  #something with your glyph
  count = @glyph_counts[@glyph.item]
end
```